# User Capabilities are not available in WP REST permission callback?

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles, rest-api, capabilities, permissions

I want to only permit the execution of specific admin tasks for users who are

1. currently logged in to the wp admin panel (via [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)) and who
2. have a specific capability (via [current_user_can](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)).

To do this check; I do:

```
register_rest_route(
                        'plugin/v1',
                        '/resource',
                        [
                            [
                                'methods'             => 'GET',
                                'permission_callback' => function ( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
                                    if(! is_user_logged_in()) { return false;}
                                    if(! current_user_can('edit_pages')) { return false;}
                            if(wp_verify_nonce($request->get_header('X-WP-Nonce'),'wp_rest') === false ) { return false; }
                                },
                                'callback'            => 'controller',
                                'args'                => $args
                            ]
                        ]
                    );
```

`is_user_logged_in()` is passed, but `current_user_can` fails, even if I try it with some really basic capability like `edit_pages`, and run the request as an `Administrator` user.

Interestingly, if I echo `json_encode(wp_get_current_user())` in that permission callback, I can see that the `caps` property, supposed to represent the user's capabilities, is an empty array. So the admin user has no assigned capabilities, although he's an admin user. Anyone may know why this happens? Because, according to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/checking-user-capabilities/#user-roles-and-capabilities):

**Every user logged into WordPress is automatically assigned specific User capabilities depending on their User role.**

This does not seem to be the case here??

Comment: How are you authenticating your requests? It's worth a mention that `WP_User::$caps` is layered on top of any capabilities granted by the user's role - it's not unusual for it to be empty.

Comment: I do both authentication and authorization within the `permission_callback`. As stated in my question, I'm using `is_user_logged_in`, hence for authentication, and then `current_user_can` for authorization. At the moment, it looks like the user is not set because I did not correctly send the nonce, leading to wp nulling the admin user. On the point of figuring it out; will post my answer below.

Comment: you ask a question about your code without showing it.... for the record you don't need to check if user is logged in, but that is unlikely to be your problem

Comment: @DevelJoe [Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) can not (or at the very least should not) be accomplished in a `permission_callback` - the request should already be authenticated at that point, which allows WordPress to retrieve the appropriate user. You have to send a nonce generated for a current user session in a `X-WP-Nonce` header, use a username/app password bearer token in an `Authentication` header, or use some mechanism provided by another plugin. Are you doing one of these things?

Comment: @bosco I guess my answer posted below answers your concern about authentication.

Comment: I'm not seeing any code in your question to debug or diagnose

Comment: Added some sample code, which will imho not really provide further details, being the reason why I omitted any code in my question. But uty to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found the problem. The issue was indeed that I was not passing the nonce of the request in the proper way. Because, as I found in the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication):

> If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0,
> turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re
> logged into WordPress.

So I'm guessing that this was the actual issue. So I'm now passing a nonce via the `X-WP-Nonce` header, with the nonce being used being generated, also as the docs say, via:

`wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');`

Now, I can indeed retrieve the capabilities of the concerned `Administrator` user, and `current_user_can()` authorization within the `permission_callback` works.

What astonished me is that (and I'm not sure if I'm understanding that correctly); you cannot pass custom strings to `wp_create_nonce` when you use `REST`, as you can do it using the legacy `wp_ajax` API. The above-mentioned failed when I specified any string different from `wp_rest` to the value of `wp_create_nonce`. Just feels odd to me that the string used to generate a nonce for like 30 different `REST` requests **MUST** be the same string, always.

And finally, after `current_user_can`, I'm also checking the nonce via:

```
wp_verify_nonce(
$request->get_header('X-WP-Nonce'),
'wp_rest'
);
```

Just because the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication) say nothing about doing this automatically if you're not using WP's built-in Javascript API. So I guessed you have to do it on your own in such a scenario, but as it seems, WP actually does it for you also in this scenario, so that part can be omitted.

Comment: you shouldn't need to check for that nonce, the API is doing that for you when authenticating the request

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but the docs are not really clear about that aspect. Although my request failed when I did not generate the nonce with the `wp_rest` string, so I guess you're right. Meaning you never use `wp_verify_nonce` in such a scenario?

Comment: Correct - short of something like using custom nonce actions in the body of the request to verify the intent of more atomic interactions, you will never need to verify a nonce in your REST handlers. Other authentication mechanisms use different means - sometimes just a bearer token with no cookie and no nonce, for example. WordPress handling authentication and request security as a layer separate from routes and endpoints enables them to be written in such a way that your code need not account for the many, many ways in which authentication could occur (unlike the legacy AJAX handler system).